# Is there a special name for matrices $A^T A$ and $A A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I'm looking for a special name for matrices $A^T A$ and $A A^T$. "Symmetric" and "Positive semi-definite" are too general terms. These matrices have special properties, so they should have a special name.

The closest I have found so far is "Scatter matrix" for $A^T A$, but it only applies to column-centered matrices.

Comment: I generally call them "Gram matrices".  To be precise you could call them the Gram matrix of columns and the Gram matrix of rows.

Comment: How is "symmetric positive semi-dfinite" too general? Could you exhibit a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix that is not of this form?

Comment: @avid19 your comment is false.  See [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call them Gramian matrices. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix